# Copying object data and updating the database using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have two same objects of type 'Monitor' that represents the data that will be written to the database. The first object X has the data that I want to update in the database. Object Y is the one that was read from the database using entity framework.

I want to copy all the data of object X, except the ID, to Object Y. The reason I want to do so is that I've already got object X populated but I don't want to start copying each property value one by one. So in short, I want to merge the data (Except the ID) from object X to object Y, which Object Y is the object which is attached to the context. then when I run Savechanged(), object Y will be updated with the new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you need exactly is this:

First `Attach` the detached object X to the `DataContext` the change it's state to `EntityState.Modified`, the run `SaveChanges` and it will update the database based on your changes.

Just remember to set the `ID` of `Y` to `ID` of `X` which is the primary key AFAIU.

For more information look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676